# Python Multiprocessing start a process during a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have a simple for loop scanning through a document, and I want it to start that 2nd process while continuing through the main for loop

```
def main():
    combatDelta = datetime.timedelta(0, 5, 0 , 0)
    combatlog = []
    othercombats = []
    times = []
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        firstCombat = True
        counter = 0
        combatstart = None
        lastTime = None
        betweencombatDetla = None
        start = timer.time()
        for line in file:
            temp2 = line
            temp2 = temp2.split("::")
            temp = temp2[0]
            temp = temp.split(":")
            time = datetime.datetime(2000 + int(temp[0]), int(temp[1]), int(temp[2]), int(temp[3]), int(temp[4]),
                                     int(temp[5][0] + temp[5][1]), int(temp[5][3]) * 100000)
            if counter == 0:
                combatstart = time
                lastTime = time
            else:
                betweencombatDetla = time - lastTime
                lastTime = time
                if betweencombatDetla > combatDelta:
                    print("next combat")
                    if firstCombat:
                        p = Process(target=combatAnalyis())
                        p.start()
                        firstCombat = False



            combattime = time - combatstart
            if firstCombat:
                combatlog.append(line)
            else:
                othercombats.append(line)
            print(len(combatlog))
            print(len(othercombats))
            counter += 1
```

(sorry if the code is a bit of a mess)
(The purpose is to, while continuing the for loop to execute the "combatAnalysis function, for now this function is just a for loop printing numbers as a placeholder to show that the multiprocessing is working)
Going by the documentation I tried implementing this, but it's now first executing the 2nd function and not continuing the for loop in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

Try running the thread using the threading library. Use `threading.Thread(target=combatAnalyis)` and then just use `.start()` to start it. Make sure you don't add parantheses-() after the name of your target function.

Comment: That seems to have helped, any reason why the Threading module did work, but Multiprocessing did (Just trying to learn and see what I did wrong here)

Comment: Don't know. Try removing the parantheses after combatAnalyis when you use multiprocessing. That causes all kinds of problems.